# Binary conflict with git merge

Tags: git, pdf, binary, latex

After merging with the remote repository I have a conflict with a PDF file generated by my code.

The file **Graphs.pdf** can not longer be created in my local folder, it is always automatically renamed to **Graphs_computer_name_...._Conflict.pdf**.

Even if I create the file myself with touch it is automatically renamed.

Answer (score 0):

git can not merge binary files automatically. You should merge use merge tools which can handle pdf to do merge manually. Or specify the merge strategy to tell git to use remote version or local version of your binary files.

By the way, it is not recommended to add generated files to repository.

Comment: I do not want git to merge this file. I want just want to be able to create again Graphs.pdf in my  local folder.

Comment: @MuntramvanChen then you should remove those pdfs from repository firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to not put the binary/generated files in the repository.
Make sure your maven/gradle plugins are capable enough to generate the same on anyone's machine who pull the same code.
Now, when the maven build happens, the binary should be generated again.